# Unable to click on the bootstrap editor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented the code for bootstrap editor by referring to the code in http://www.bootply.com/87859#

I am able to write the code in editor.

But when i select a text and click on any controls to change it to Bold, Italic or some other control, it is not changing. Can you please help me here to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I works with me when you select the text which you want to edit.